# Ошибка «The table is full» при преобразовании таблицы в Memory

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Есть MyISAM таблица размером около 30МБ и 200 000 записей, хочу сделать из нее Memory (для тестирования), но не выходит из-за ошибки:

> ```
> SQL query:   ALTER TABLE `tablica`
> ENGINE = MEMORY 
>
> MySQL said:  
> #1114 - The table '#sql-70c8_1c' is full
> ```

На сервере 2ГБ оперативки, `max_heap_table_size = 1048576000`.

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

тебе нужна переменная tmp_table_size

Comment: Исправил tmp_table_size, но проблема осталась :(

Comment: Создал новую таблицу MEMORY и скопировал туда записи из MyISAM. Поместилось только 150,000 и они заняли гиг, тогда как в MyISAM они весят 26.1 MiB :(

Answer (score 0):

В таблицах MEMORY значения занимают больше места. Например, при DYNAMIC-формате строк (для InnoDB, MyISAM и др.) всё нормально, лишнего не скушается, ограничивается только максимальная длина строки.

А MEMORY-таблицы всегда имеют FIXED-формат строк. Потому под любую строку будет выделяться <макс-длина-строки> * 3 байт места. Заодно, проверьте типы строк. В таблицах MEMORY так же нет строк типа TEXT.